# Set transaction isolation level in torque

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-torque

How do I set the transaction isolation level for a specific transaction when using torque?

My problem may be that I am using the org.apache.torque.util.Transaction class like this:

```
Connection con=Transaction.begin();
// Use connection
con.commit();
```

Con does have a setTransactionIsolation method, but the documentation for that method says:
"If this method is called during a transaction, the result is implementation-defined."

which seems odd, since the only way to get a Connection object is to begin a transaction. So the only time I can call that method, is during a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `con.setTransactionIsolation(...)` directly after getting the connection via `Connection con=Transaction.begin();`. The transaction is not yet started in the JDBC sense at this point. Make sure to call `con.commit()` or `con.rollback()` later, releasing the connection back to a connection pool via `con.close()` while a transaction is in progress is undefined behavior.

Reference: [org.apache.torque.util.Torque Transaction source](http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Database-ORM/Torque/org/apache/torque/util/Transaction.java.htm)

Comment: So when does the transaction start? When i do the first select/update?

Comment: Yes, typically. From JDBC specification: "When to start a new transaction is a decision made implicitly by either the JDBC 
driver or the underlying data source. Although some data sources implement an 
explicit “begin transaction” statement, there is no JDBC API to do so. Typically, a 
new transaction is started when the current SQL statement requires one and there is 
no transaction already in place. Whether or not a given SQL statement requires a 
transaction is also specified by SQL:2003."

Comment: BTW since this is a pooled connection don't forget to restore the original isolation level after `commit()` or `rollback()` and before `con.close()`

Comment: Thanks. I had not thought about the need to restore it to the default level.